# Why is this code not returning a null matrix?

Tags: c++, c

Why is the code pasted below not returning a null matrix, but istead returning a matrix with NaN along principal diagonal?
where am i doing wrong?

```
if(g = 0)
{
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    for(j=N;j<2*N;j++)
        {
        fnd[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

else
{
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
    for(p=0;p<N;p++)
        {
        if(p!=i)
            {
            fnd[i][i+N]+=g*g*3.*fabs(x[i]-x[p])*fabs(x[i+N]-x[p+N]) /fabs(pow(fabs(pow(fabs(x[i]-x[p]),2.)+g*g*pow(fabs(x[i+N]-x[p+N]),2.)+h*h*pow(fabs(x[i+2*N]-x[p+2*N]),2)),2.5) );
            }
        }
    for(j=N;j<2*N;j++)
        {
              //offdiagonal terms<------
        if(i!=j)
            {
            fnd[i][j]=-3.*g*g*fabs(x[i]-x[j-N])* fabs(x[i+N]-x[j])/fabs(pow(fabs(pow(x[i]-x[j-N],2.)+g*g*pow(x[i+N]-x[j],2.)+h*h*pow(x[i+2*N]-x[j+N],2)),2.5) )  ;
            }
          }
    }
}


//-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: your code is in complete or what ??

Comment: Also, why are you using C++ tag?

Comment: @Karthik the code is incomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among possibly other things (this isn't complete code), the `if(g = 0)` should use `==` instead of plain `=`. As written, `g` will always be assigned zero, which will then always evaluate to false, and so the loops that initialize the matrix to all zeroes *won't* actually run. Instead, the whole `else` block will run with `g` being zero, which I assume is unexpected.

Comment: Thanks n--->inf number of times, i am new to C and i spent half of today's morning for that! damn! i should have posted my question earlier!

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning g with zero in the first if conditional check and thus is returns zero and so the first if conditional clause is not executed. you are supposed to use '==' comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not initializing matrix elements in case if g != 0 and p != i, i != j.

Answer (score 0):

when g == 0 (assuming you corrected it ) you are making the second half of the matrix as null from Nth column 2*Nth column (again assuming the rows = N and columns = 2*N) then first half of the matrix is uninitialized.

if your aim is only to initialize it to zero

```
int array[20][20] = {0}
```

The compiler would fill the unwritten entries with zeros.